# Best topology for a power Low-Pass Filter

Tags: power, filter, low-pass, passive-filter

I am in need of a LPF on a power line, something that carries up to 5 A (at 36 V). I am trying to leave the power transmission at DC unaffected, while suppressing noise components above 100 kHz. I would like to power loss to be under a Watt, which limits path resistance at DC to about 40 mOhms.

My application is a mobile one, so I'm looking for a compact solution. My problem is that I have little feel as to the various filter topology trade-offs - particularly resulting size.

I (fairly arbitrarily) set my corner frequency to 100 Hz, and would like to achieve 40 dB of attenuation by 100 kHz - a roll-off of about -13 dB/decade or -4 dB/octave.

My go-to LPF is a 1st order R-C circuit in Half-Section configuration. However, to achieve that DC resistance would require a chunky capacitor (30+ mF).

Next, I looked at a L-C or L-R (of some order), or a Pi/T configuration, and I start to get lost in the options! So far, the most promising I see is the first-order L-C, but ... inductors are pretty big, too...

My question therefore is: is there a "typical" configuration usually used for such filters on power lines, where minimising size and DC resistance is more critical than sharp frequency roll-off? Is there a specific topology would usually be most appropriate here? Should I be looking at a completely different way to implement such a LPF?

I have assumed that any active filters are inappropriate for such power applications, but if there are suitable active filter designs/components, I'd like to hear about them...

Comment: You also need to decide that if you use an RLC filter what damping ratio minimum your output recipient circuit can tolerate. I mention this because if your input supply rises sharply there will be overshoot on the output and that may cause an over voltage situation and bust your load. I'd be considering an LC with a resistor in parallel with the inductor thus you get best dc performance and damping control from the resistor. Your inductor will not be an 0805 LOL.

Comment: 1. Better to prevent noise from getting in the line to begin with than to let it in then try to filter it out. Have you looked at where your noise is coming from and how you could reduce it at the source? 2. Your power line itself has some inductance. So a capacitor at one or both ends can form an LC filter. This is the most common way of filtering power lines.

Comment: 3. Are you sure your noise is differential between the power line and its return? If not you might rather look for a common mode choke rather than the filter I think you are trying to design.

Comment: @Andyaka: Good point. In this case, I do not expect any fast input changes, but the output is tolerant to overshoots of 2x. I'd like to get critical damping, of course, but it's not a key design driver (I don't think). Yes - definitely looking to be larger than an 0805 for anything 5A :)

Comment: @Phonon: 1. Yes, agreed it is nicer to remove a signal where it is introduced. In this case, it is the output of a Boost converter (that switches at 100kHz+) that I am trying to isolate from a system sensitive to periodic noise downstream (sandworm?). What I am doing here is my attempt to remove at source :)
2. True, but line is short - all on a single small PCB. I would not expect much inductance to be added here, not to the order required to counter low-frequency noise like this (although I may be able to find some way to boost this..).
3. Will think now about the nature of my noise!